# Rank of a left multiplication by $P$ when $P$ has rank $m$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> If $A$ is left multiplication by $P$ on a space of linear transformations, and $P$ has rank $m$, what is the rank of $A$?

Outline of my solution:

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and $\{x_1, ..., x_m, ..., x_n\}$ be a basis of vector space $V$, such that $\{x_1, ..., x_m\}$ is a basis of range of $P$. Let $\{y_1, ..., y_n\}$ be a dual basis, s.t. $y_j(x_i) = \delta_{ij}$ is the kronecker delta function.
Then $X_{ij}(x) = y_j(x)*x_i$ is a basis of $L(V)$ space of linear transformations on $V$.

Let's find an image of $PX$. Any linear transformation $X$ is a linear combination of basis $X_{ij}$, s.t. $X=\sum_{ij}^n\alpha_{ij}X_{ij}$. Then $PX = \sum_{ij}^n\alpha_{ij}PX_{ij} = \sum_{ij}^n\alpha_{ij}y_j(x)Px_i$.

Sine $P$ has rank $m$, $Px_i = \sum_k^mP_{ki}x_k$ is a linear combination of $m$ vectors.

Now $PX = \sum_j^n\sum_k^m \big[\sum_i^nP_{ki}\alpha_{ij}\big]\cdot \big[y_j(x)x_k\big] = \sum_j^n\sum_k^m \beta_{jk}\cdot X_{jk}$ is a linear combinations of $n \cdot m$ elements and therefore $A$ has rank $n \cdot m$.

Is my solution correct? Is there a better/simpler/more intuitive solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer of $ m \cdot n$ is definitely correct. I think your answer is on the right track and it seems to have the right idea (I didn't fully verify it, because I was too lazy to read through all the indices).

The general theorem is this:

> **Theorem:**
>
> Let $U,V,W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $\Bbb{F}$, and fix a particular linear transformation $P\in L(V,W)$ (say of rank $r$). Define the "left-composition by $P$" map $A: L(U,V) \to L(U,W)$ by
> \begin{align}
> A(Q) = P \circ Q
> \end{align}
> Then, $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(P) \cdot \dim(U)$.

To get an intuitive feel for why this should be true, let's choose $U=V=W = \Bbb{F}^n$, and rather than thinking in terms of linear transformations, let's think in terms of $n \times n$ matrices. Now, as a special case, let's choose $P$ to be the $n \times n$ matrix with the block representation:
\begin{align}
P = \begin{pmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
with $0$ being zero matrices of appropriate size. Clearly $\text{rank}(P) = r$ (it's the simplest matrix with rank $r$). Now, write an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix $Q$ in block form as
\begin{align}
Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_r \\
Q_*
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
where $Q_r$ is an $r \times n$ matrix consisting of the first $r$ rows of $Q$, and $Q_*$ is the  matrix consisting of the remaining rows of $Q$ (in this case, it is $(n-r) \times n$).
Then, we have that
\begin{align}
A(Q) &:= P\cdot Q \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_r \\
Q_*
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
Q_r \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
In words, the image of $A$ consists of those $n \times n$ matrices, such that the last $n-r$ rows are all zero. This subspace has dimension $r \times n$, because the set $\{E_{ij}: 1 \leq i \leq r, \quad 1 \leq j \leq n\}$ is a basis ($E_{ij}$ being the $n \times n$ matrix with $1$ in the $ij$ entry and $0$ elsewhere). Hence, $\text{rank}(A) = r \times n$.

---

The above computation was very easy because we chose a very simple matrix $P$. But in reality, there is not much generality lost, because by choosing appropriate bases we can always bring a linear map $P \in L(V,W)$ to have an identity matrix in the top left and zero elsewhere.

To prove the general statement, I'll make use of the notation as in the theorem. First of all, since $P \in L(V,W)$ has rank $r$, we can construct* a basis $\beta$ of $V$, and a basis $\gamma$ of $W$ such that the matrix representation of $P$ is
\begin{align}
[P]_{\beta}^{\gamma} = \begin{pmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Next, fix a basis $\alpha$ for $U$ (there is no need to choose any special $\alpha$; we just need to pick one, and keep it fixed for the rest of our discussion). Now, denote $\Phi_{\alpha, \gamma}: L(U,W) \to M_{\dim(W) \times \dim(U)}(\Bbb{F})$ by
\begin{align}
\Phi_{\alpha,\gamma}(S) := [S]_{\alpha}^{\gamma}
\end{align}
In words, $\Phi_{\alpha,\gamma}$ is the isomorphism which sends a linear transformation $S \in L(U,W)$ to its matrix representation $[S]_{\alpha}^{\gamma}$. Now, I hope you know that composing with an isomorphism keeps the rank the same, hence:
\begin{align}
\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(\Phi_{\alpha,\gamma} \circ A)
\end{align}
Therefore, to figure out what $\text{rank}(A)$ is, we just need to figure out the rank of $\Phi_{\alpha,\gamma} \circ A$. This is pretty easy. To do this, let's first figure out what the image of this map is: for any $Q \in L(U,V)$, we have that
\begin{align}
\big(\Phi_{\alpha,\gamma} \circ A \big)(Q) &:= \Phi_{\alpha,\gamma}\big( A(Q)\big) \\
&:= \Phi_{\alpha,\gamma} \big( P\circ Q\big) \\
&:= \big[ P \circ Q \big]_{\alpha}^{\gamma} \\
&= \big[ P \big]_{\beta}^{\gamma} \cdot \big[ Q \big]_{\alpha}^{\beta} \tag{$\ddot{\smile}$}\\\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_r \\
Q_{*}
\end{pmatrix} \\\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
Q_r \\
0
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
In $ ( \ddot{\smile} ),$ I made use of the fact that the matrix representation of a composition is the product of matrix representations, which I hope you know/ can prove easily.
Hence, the image of $\Phi_{\alpha,\gamma} \circ A$ consists of those $ \big(\dim(W) \times \dim(U) \big)$ matrices, whose last $\big( \dim(U) - r \big)$ rows are all zero; this consitutes a subspace of dimension $r \times \dim(U)$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\text{rank}(A) &= \text{rank}(\Phi_{\alpha,\gamma} \circ A) \\
&= r \times \dim(U) \\
&:= \text{rank}(P) \cdot \dim(U),
\end{align}
which is what we wanted to show.

---

*: We can construct the bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ easily as follows: first, construct a basis $\{\eta_1, \dots, \eta_{\dim(V) -r}\}$ for $\ker(P)$ (by rank nullity, it has dimension $\dim(V) - r$). Now, extend this to a basis $\{\eta_1, \dots, \eta_{\dim(V) -r}\} \cup \{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_r\}$ for the whole space $V$. Now, reorder the basis elements to get
\begin{align}
\beta = \{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_r ; \, \, \eta_1, \dots, \eta_{\dim(V) - r}\}
\end{align}
Then, $\{P(\xi_1), \dots, P(\xi_r)\}$ will be a basis for $\text{image}(P)$; now extend this to a basis $\gamma$ of $W$ (without changing the order). Then, with such a choice of ordered basis, the matrix $[P]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$ will have the desired block format.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is finite-dimensional, you can assume that $P\in K^{n\times n}$ is a matrix. Then, if $X\in K^{n\times n}$, $X = [x_1|\ldots|x_n]$,
$$
A(X) = PX = [Px_1|\ldots|Px_n],
$$
that is,
$$
\operatorname{im}A = \{[y_1|\ldots|y_n] : y_i\in\operatorname{im}P\,\forall i\}
$$
and therefore $\operatorname{rank}A = n\cdot\operatorname{rank}P$.